# TensorFlow not importing when using PyCharm from Desktop Entry or Launcher

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, tensorflow, pycharm

TensorFlow is installed properly on my computer and I can import it and run code with it fine in terminals, PyCharm (opened with pycharm.sh command from a terminal window), and other editors.

However, if I start PyCharm from Launcher, it gives me the following error when importing TensorFlow

```
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

I have deleted jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop and re-created it through Tools -> Create Desktop Entry multiple times.  I also tried opening up PyCharm with pycharm.sh from the terminal and locking the opened application to Launcher.  No matter what I do, PyCharm opened through any of the GUI methods is not able to import TensorFlow.

I compared all the run settings and everything in PyCharm and couldn't really find any differences.

What could it be that does not allow me to import TensorFlow when PyCharm is not opened through the command line?

Below is the entire block of error code I get in PyCharm.

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-41389fad42b5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/opt/miniconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "/opt/miniconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

Comment: It's an install issue, but it sounds like it's an issue with miniconda that we don't support. Whatever the case, we track these issues on our github page. Please file an issue there.